# How to retrieve all Meteor Mongo collection names as Javascript array?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I tried to use:

```
MongoInternals.defaultRemoteCollectionDriver().mongo.db.listCollections()
```

in order to get all collection names in meteor database, but it returns a very long JSON, in which i couldn't find the pure collection names. (see the attached image)

[image]

How can I get meteor collection names in a following format:

```
["test1", "test2", "users"...]
```

Comment: `listCollections` returns a `MongoCollection` which you would iterate over, calling `.getNamespace()` to get the names. Please note the returned value you are seeing is **not** JSON but rather the console's interpretation of the object, hence items such as `[Function]`

Comment: @PaulS. thanks for clearing this out I will implement code based on this information.

Answer (score 8):

Ok, here is the working code, thanks @PaulS.

```
db = MongoInternals.defaultRemoteCollectionDriver().mongo.db;
collections = db.listCollections();

collections.each(function(n, collection){
  if(collection){
    console.log( collection.name );
  }
});
```